# Adding React in pre existing Electron project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, electron-forge

Haven't seen this posted anywhere, I am in the middle of an electron project in vanilla js, I want to add the whole react framework (like the create-react-app command does) but I dont want it to break the rest of the project. Is there a way to add it now with the whole webpack, babel, and all the other needed libraries in the same directory or file that my app is already in?

I have seen how to start a react project and then add electron, how to use elctron forge to make electron start with react, but saw nothing of how to add to pre existing project.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Official docs: [How to create an Electron app with React and Electron Forge](https://www.electronforge.io/guides/framework-integration/react#integrate-react-code)